# 401 - Authentication required error on server

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-401

I have a Java REST endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@ApiOperation(value="Login a user with a username and password and return a jwt")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code=200, message="Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code=404, message="Not Found")
})
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response login(@ApiParam(required = true) UserLoginRequest userLogin, @Context HttpServletRequest request)  {
    LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
    try {
```

I use Postman to test it on my localhost.

```
POST https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface/rest/user/reset/forgot-password

{
    "email": "richard@test.com",
    "recaptcha": "xxxx"
}
```

I get a valid response as expected.

```
HTTP Status 200 OK
```

However, when I try test it on another server:

```
POST https://dev.server.co/corporateInterface/rest/user/reset/forgot-password

{
    "email": "richard@test.com",
    "recaptcha": "xxxx"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication required
```

The code is the same, the calling request is the same (different url).

How do I get it to work on the server?

**More info**

Postman message:

[image]

Comment: why don't you check the log on the dev.server.co?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. It is as if the request is being blocked before it can even hit the endpoint.

Comment: I guess there should be something that does the authentication before the server process your request.

Comment: I think you are right. Our application has a filter chain. I need to check that.

Comment: You were right, we have a filter that is returning a 401 if the request is not logged in.  - thanks for the advise.